# Mac : LaserJet driver stopped working

Tags: network-printer, macos-mojave, hp-laserjet

(Basically I got this fixed somehow by trail and error, but I am still posting, because I am interested in possible explanations for what has happened and why):

On my home network, I have a Mac (running Mojave 10.14.6) and a Windows 10 PC, and also a HP Laserjet 2100TN. This setup worked for months perfectly fine, until today, when I wanted to print again from my Mac, nothing was received by the printer. I did the following checks:

- Printer reachable via ping
- Printerqueue shows the printer Green, the queue displays as Idle, showing no job waiting.
- No error message from the applications I printed from (Libre Office).

To see whether the problem is from the application, I also tried printing a page from another application (Cot Text Editor), and created from Libre Office with "print to PDF" a PDF document, which I then tried to print from the Preview. Same effect.

I then transfered this PDF to the Windows PC and printed from there. Printing worked fine.

I rebooted the Mac and the printer, but same effect. No printing possible, and no error message.

A trouble-shooting page I found on [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/de-de/guide/mac-help/mh14002/mac) suggests to add my printer a second time, in order to create a new print queue. I tried this, and here I got for the first time a hint on what may go on:

I'm identifying my printer in the setup dialogue via its IP address (it has assigned a fixed address in my homenetwork), and when I added it a second time as suggested using the default settings, i.e.:

*Protocol: Internet Printing Protocol - IPP*

the model, "HP LaserJet  2100 Series", was immediately recognized; but after confirming that I indeed want to add the same printer again, I got the error message

**Unable to conntect to *(my IP address)* due to an error**

without stating what kind of error it would be.

In the printer setup dialogue, the last field was at this time already automatically filled with "HP LaserJet  2100 Series", but now I tried, just for fun, to replace this by "Generic PCL printer". After doing this, I could create the new printer, and printing worked with the new one fine.

To sum it up:

Printing using these setting "LaserJet 2100", which would exactly correspond to my printer, still does not work.

Printing to the same printer using the setting "Generic PCL" does work.

From this, I conclude that it somehow must be a driver problem. If this would have occured on a fresh system, I would simply conclude that the LaserJet driver has a bug, but it does not explain, why printing worked fine for a long time, but now suddenly doesn't do anymore.

There also hasn't been an update recently. To verify this, I used [this](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/01/11/dates-app-macos-updates-mac/) guide and saw that the I didn't have any installation updates during the past 3 weeks.

What I did get recently, was an automatic update of the firmware from my FritzBox router, but I don't see how this could explain the problems I encountered.

As I said, I can print now with the PCL driver, but if anybody has some idea of why I had to go through all these hassles, I would be glad to hear some opinions.

Answer (score 2):

HP have a global issue right now - one of their certificates expired this week.
The interweb is full of it.

Try the apps/drivers from the App Store, Apple trusts those. Search "hp printer"

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. I went to App Store and searched for "hp printer", like your screenshot shows, but "HP smart" seems to be  for the HP OfficeJet Pro 9020 - a different model than I have -, and "HP Easy Scan" implies by its name that it is for a HP scanner and hence not suitable for me either. Which one do you suggest to install?

Comment: If the one on the App Store isn't suitable, you'll have to wait until HP fix their certificate &/or issue an app update.